# Spree Commerce 2.3 - Add Extra Amount to Line Items

Tags: spree

I have a Spree Commerce (v2.3.8) store. I need to add an extra amount to some **Line Items** of an **Order**. This amount will be added automatically depending on the rol of the customer and not by entering any promotion code.

Example: *If one of the variants in the order has a price of $10 and I need to add a 35% extra, I want this variant to have a price of $13.50.*

I was trying to do this using [Adjustments](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/adjustments.html) on Line Items, but didn't get anywhere. And sincerely, I don't know if that is the way to do.

I am looking for some advice on how to do this since I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up adding the percentage in the OrderPopulator model when adding the variant to the order. Not the most elegant solution, but at least it works.